# To update specific column values based on other columns in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table whereby i need to update the value on one column based on the values from 2 other columns, I extract the data and put it in other new #temp table
where the format of the snippet data is as follows

```
DOC_GUID     NAME   Value   Timestamp 
--------     ----   -----   ---------
1111         V1     AC      1134
1111         V2     AB      1134
1112         V1     N       1234
1112         V2     AB      1234
1113         V1     AC      1334
1113         V2     N       1334
1114         V1     N       1434
1114         V2     N       1434
```

I need to update the values to become like this

```
DOC_GUID     NAME   Value   Timestamp 
--------     ----   -----   ---------
1111         V1     AC      1134
1111         V2     AC      1134
1112         V1     AB      1234
1112         V2     AB      1234
1113         V1     AC      1334
1113         V2     AC      1334
1114         V1     N       1434
1114         V2     N       1434
```

I tried to write out the logic as follows, but it cant be executed at all

```
UPDATE #temp
SET Value = CASE WHEN (A.DOC_GUID = B.DOC_GUID
                      FROM #temp A inner join #temp B
                      ON A.Value= 'AC' OR 
                      B.Value = 'AC')
                 THEN 'AC'
                 WHEN (A.DOC_GUID = B.DOC_GUID
                      FROM #temp A inner join #temp B
                      ON A.Value= 'AB' OR 
                      B.Value = 'AB')
                 THEN 'AB' END
```

Comment: 1. So you want for each `DOC_GUID` to `UPDATE Value` to whatever value the row for V1 has?  2. Which SQL server version are you using?

Comment: Are there ever more than two versions for a given `DOC_GUID` ?

Comment: Nope i want the `value` to be updated to AC first if there is `value` of AC, next AB if there is AB and lastly to N if there's no AC or AB, and I am using sql 2014

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure what you mean, but for every `DOC_GUID` there's only `NAME` of V1 and V2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DDL:

```
declare @tbl table (DOC_GUID int, NAME varchar(3), Value varchar(3),  Timestamp int );
insert into @tbl values
(1111,'V1','AC',1134),
(1111,'V2','AB',1134),
(1112,'V1','AB',1234),
(1112,'V2','N',1234),
(1113,'V1','AC',1334),
(1113,'V2','N',1334),
(1114,'V1','N',1434),
(1114,'V2','N',1434);
```

Update query:

```
update t1 set t1.Value = t2.Value
from @tbl t1 join (
    select *,
           -- here I use case statement to make AC come before AB
           row_number() over (partition by DOC_GUID order by case when [Value] = 'AC' then 'AA' else [Value] end) rn
    from @tbl
) t2 on t1.DOC_GUID = t2.DOC_GUID
where t2.rn = 1
```

Comment: Nope i want the `Value` to be updated to AC first if there is `Value` of AC, next AB if there is AB but no AC, and lastly to N if there's no AC or AB

Comment: thanks! btw the value  partition should be`partition by DOC_GUID order by case when [Value] = 'AC' then 'AC' else [Value] end`, i think you mistype it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using window function and an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) over (partition by doc_guid) as use_value
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by doc_guid order by priority) as seqnum
            from t left join
                 (values ('AC', 1),
                         ('AB', 2),
                         ('N', 3)
                 ) v(value, priority)
                 on v.value = t.value
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set value = use_value
    where use_value <> value;
```

This approach has two major advantages.

First, it is quite simple to change the priorities because these are embedded in the `VALUES()` clause.

Second, the outer `where` clause only updates the rows that need to be updated.

This should also have good performance characteristics.

Comment: useful for my case

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `CASE` along with an `EXISTS` clause:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Value = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp t2
                              WHERE t1.DOC_GUID = t2.DOC_GUID AND
                                    t2.Value = 'AC')
                 THEN 'AC'
                 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp t2
                              WHERE t1.DOC_GUID = t2.DOC_GUID AND
                                    t2.Value = 'AB')
                 THEN 'AB'
                 ELSE 'N' END
FROM #temp t1;
```

Comment: i will have syntax error if i use this as i cant give temp table a name